# Idris 2 cannot find Control.Linear.LIO module

Tags: idris

I'm trying to write some Idris 2 code reimplementing the examples shown in the [Idris2 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.00480.pdf).
When trying to import the `L` type by setting
`import Control.Linear.LIO` and loading the file, I get the following error in the Repl:

> Error: Module Control.Linear.LIO not found

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly include contrib as a package. Run Idris like

```
$ idris2 -p contrib filename.idr
```